# "I can't help it." Why help?

Tags: word-usage

Why do we use the verb *help* in sentences such as the following to mean something like *refrain from*?

- I try not to eat junk, but I can't help it.
- I couldn't help laughing.
- I can't help but admire her bravery.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's simply one of the ascribed meanings.

Comment: @Karl, could you explain *ascribed meanings* and give some examples in a regular answer?

Comment: There's nothing to explain. It's just one of the things that the verb can mean.

Comment: Ok, Karl, you can stop being helpful now

Comment: @Karl. Thanks, I now understand *ascribed meaning*. What I find interesting about this expression is that it is only used in the negative. We don't say: *I try to avoid eating junk and I can help it.*

Comment: Are you asking for the etymology of this expression?

Comment: @Pitarou, I am hoping someone can shed light on when and why the expression *can't help* came to mean *refrain from, avoid, stop, prevent oneself*, and as corollary why it is not used in the positive.

Comment: There's also the _not if I can help it_ usage, which isn't the same negative construction as in the OP.

Comment: I also ran a google search on "can help it" without "can't help it" and found some positive examples, though not too many. _"Avoid Including Bulky JS Libraries If You Can Help It"_, for instance. Need to better filter out IT-related headlines like "X can help IT".

Comment: @ivancho sorry(,) I couldn't help (it). ;)

Comment: I think *help* is a negative polarity item. It  also occurs in interrogatives and conditional protases *... if you can help it* etc. (Oh, as just mentioned in Barries answer below!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two of the OED’s definitions of *help* are relevant. Definition 11a is:

> To remedy, obviate, prevent, cause to be otherwise. (With can, cannot, or
>   some equivalent.) In earlier use usually in passive ‘it cannot be
>   helped’, later in active with personal subject ‘I cannot help it’ = I cannot do anything to remedy or prevent it.

Definition 11b is:

> To prevent oneself from, avoid, refrain from, forbear; to do otherwise
>   than. (With can, cannot.)

It is true that in both senses *help* is often used with a negative word such as *no, scarcely* or *hardly*, but that is not always the case. For one thing, it can be used in a question, as in Trollope’s ‘How can I help it that I am not a man and able to work for my bread?’ It can also occur in an *if* clause **following** a negative, as it did in Hugh Walpole’s ‘I thought he should not offend the King if he could help it.’ In sense 11a, Pepys even used it without a negative at all: ‘One thing there is in his accounts that I fear may touch me; but I shall help it, I hope’

Comment: Thanks. You and the above commenters have answered my question.

Comment: _Can help V-ing_ is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), which can't occur outside the scope of a negative word or construction. _If_ is one such, as are questions. Again, grammatical questions should not be researched in a dictionary; that's for words, not constructions.